# Custom adapter not displaying correct information

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I have a custom adapter as written below,

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Activity activity;
private List<String> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int resource, List<String> i) {
    super(a, resource, i);
    activity = a;
    items = i;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) a
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, parent,
                false);
    }

    final CheckedTextView checkbox = (CheckedTextView) vi
            .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    checkbox.setText(items.get(position));
    Log.d("test", "testing");

    checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!checkbox.isChecked()) {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
                Log.d("Test", "checked");

                if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    checkbox.setChecked(false);
                    Log.d("test", "unchecked");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

However, my list now only shows a checkbox for every row, while it should be displaying a textview along with a checkbox. Also, my onClickListener works regardless if i touch the checkbox, or the listitem itself. Log.d should only be called when a checkbox is clicked.

Comment: could you insert the xml file simple_list_item_multiple_choice? The problem regarding the textview could be there

Comment: @GerryR that is a default component form the framework, as it starts with "android.R.layout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my list now only shows a checkbox for every row, while it should be
>   displaying a textview along with a checkbox

You are inflating a default resource from the framework but you don't set a text for your items. You can use the setText method (inherited from TextView) like this :

```
checkbox.setText(items.get(position));
```

> Log.d should only be called when a checkbox is clicked.

You are not checking if the checkbox is clicked or not (and doing an unnecessary cast on your checkbox). You can simply do something like this :

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
            if (checkbox.isChecked()){
                Log.d("Test", "testing2");
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to call `checkbox.setText` with the proper String for the parameter, something like `checkbox.setText(items.get(position));`, right after you declare your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

As npace mentioned, you didn't set the text for the view. But you will have another problem with view re-use. Since in a listview, view are re-used, your checkbox may end up being used again, but it wont remember the state it was in. You need a viewHolder class and internally cache the state of your checkboxes and set the checkbox state when it will be draw again. Here's an example of what needs to be done (I've written a re-suable multiple-selector widget):

[Multiple-Item-Selector](https://github.com/SundeepK/Multiple-Item-Selector/blob/master/multipleSelector/src/com/sun/multipleselector/impl/MultipleSelectorArrayAdapter.java)